# How to upload file using angular 1.5 with typescript?

Tags: html, typescript, angularjs-1.5

I am trying to upload a file using html 5  but I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried this

```
<input type="file" name ="file" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().selectFileForUpload(this.files)"   />
```

and inside the component i got this method:

```
public selectFileForUpload(file) {
     console.log(file[0]);
   }
```

I get this error when using above code:

```
    settings:1 Uncaught TypeError: 
angular.element(...).scope(...).selectFileForUpload is not a function
```

This works in angular 1.4 but not in 1.5.x any one have any suggestions how to accomplish this ?

I have tried to change scope() to model and $ctrl but not working either.

Comment: Where is `selectFileforUpload` defined?

Comment: inside pageImageModal.component.ts